# access this on external callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working with a library that has custom callbacks.

```
var dataTable = $("table").DataTable({
    //...

    initComplete: function(settings, json){
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

I am trying to externalize this initComplete callback. I defined a custom function:

```
var initCallback = function(settings, json){
    console.log(this);
}

var dataTable = $("table").DataTable({      
    initComplete: initCallback
}
```

It does work, but `this` does not point to the `datatable` itself. Is there a way to bind this to initCallback so I can access it?

Answer (score 0):

What if you passed "this" into your external function?

```
var initCallback = function(dataTableInstance, settings, json){
    console.log(dataTableInstance);
}

var dataTable = $("table").DataTable({      
    initComplete: function(settings, json) { initCallback(this, settings, json);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `bind` function, [here is some info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Basically, you can do some like this:

```
var initCallback = function(settings, json){
    console.log(this);
}

var dataTable = $("table").DataTable({      
    initComplete: initCallback.bind(dataTable)
}
```