# Could somebody explain to me what exactly is happening in the Dojo's ''dojo/on" module?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, dojo, widget

I started fiddling around with Dojo.js and came across a thing I don't understand.

I'm trying to create my own widget. The widget would be really simple - it would just query all images on the page and make them listen for a *'click'* event. Each click would increase the widget's *counter* attribute by 1.

Here's my take on it:

```
define(
    [                   
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/query",
        "dijit/_WidgetBase",
        "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
        "dojo/text!myProject/folder/myWidgetTemplate.html",
    ],
    function(declare, query, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template) {
        declare("MyWidget", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {

            templateString: template,
            counter: 0,

            onClick: function(evt) {
                this.counter++;
                console.log(this.counter);
            },

            postCreate: function() {
                query("img").on("click", this.onClick);
            }

        });
    }
);
```

The widget initializes and I indeed can click on images, but the console always returns *undefined*.
It seems that I'm missing some core aspect about how the *dojo/on* module works. Could somebody explain to me what exactly happens in my code?

Comment: Note: as far as i understand your widget it does not have any UI visible (because the images are anywhere in the page). In that case you can remove `_TemplatedMixin` and thus delete your `myProject/folder/myWidgetTemplate.html` template file as well as the property `templateString: template,`

Comment: You are correct, thanks for pointing that out! (The widget actually uses its own UI, I just stripped that part of the code out to make the question simpler. However, I forgot to remove the _TemplatedMixin. But it's always good to be reminded just in case, so thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `this` is pointing to the `image`, and the property `counter` is `undefined`. to accomplish this, you can use the `dojo/base/lang` module

```
define(
    [                   
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/_base/lang", //add this
        "dojo/query",
        "dijit/_WidgetBase",
        "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
        "dojo/text!myProject/folder/myWidgetTemplate.html",
    ],
    function(declare, lang, query, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template) {
        declare("MyWidget", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {

            templateString: template,
            counter: 0,

            onClick: function(evt) {
                this.counter++;
                console.log(this.counter);
            },

            postCreate: function() {
                //lang.hitch will return a new function with scope changed
                query("img").on("click", lang.hitch(this, this.onClick));
            }

        });
    }
);
```

`lang.hitch` will return a new function with the scope changed, so when you use `this` it will be pointing to the want you passed

You can avoid having to use `lang` by declaring the event in the html, for example

```
<img src="myImage.jpg" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: onClick"/>
```

Where `onClick: onClick` can be read as `event: functionName`, and `functionName` must exist in your widget.

**Note** that you can do the same using the native [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) of JavaScript by just doing

```
query("img").on("click", this.onClick.bind(this));
```

You can checkout this answer [access this on external callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439132/access-this-on-external-callback/38440423#38440423) it is not about dojo but Javascript in general.

Comment: As a side note, I would recommand to use dojo-attach-points instead of query when img are contained in the widget itself (not the case here but worth to be mentionned)

Comment: Interesting! Why is that?

Comment: `query()` requires an extra action while `attach-points` are created for free when the widget is intanciated

Comment: Just a note: I believe lang.hitch can be replaced by native .bind() if browser target is ES5 compatible.

Comment: @Radex I even gave en example of how to do it using `bind`, did you read  the entire answer?