# dojo onClick() event and javascript scope

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, dojo

I need some clarification about the function's scope in javascript and the `onClick()` event, for `dojox/mobile/Button`.

As the documentation suggests:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mobile/Button.html

I do the following, with a function call instead of write it inline:

### html

```
button.mblSimpleDialogButton(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" data-dojo-props="label: 'Ok', onClick:foo()" style="width:60%;")
```

### js

```
script(type="text/javascript").
    require([
        "dojo/on",
        "dijit/registry",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (on, registry) {
        function foo() {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

it won't work because (as far as I understand) `foo()` is defined inside another function, hence its scope is limited to that function.

But it if I place `foo()` at the global level, say:

```
script(type="text/javascript").
    require([
        "dojo/on",
        "dijit/registry",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (on, registry) {
    });
    function foo() {
        // do something
    }
```

I get a type error because `dojo` cannot find the handler:

> TypeError: this.onClick is not a function

Finally, using standard html leads the handler to work:

```
button.mblSimpleDialogButton(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" data-dojo-props="label: 'Procedi'" onClick="foo()" style="width:60%;")
```

but because `foo()` is outside the `dojo` require's function I cannot use its tools.

What is the correct approach?

## UPDATE

I don't know if it's the best way, but this works:

### html

```
button#myBtn.mblSimpleDialogButton(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" data-dojo-props="label: 'Ok'" style="width:60%;")
```

### js

```
var myBtn = dom.byId("myBtn");
on(myBtn, "click", function (e) {
    console.log("clicked!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data-dojo-props` is to be used in [Widgets with templates](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/templated/index.html) even when you can use it in other ways.

The most common example:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin"
], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: '<button data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button"' + 
            'data-dojo-props="onClick:myOnClick">My Button</button>',

        myOnClick: function(/*Event*/ evt) {
            console.log('Hello click');
        }
    });
});
```

Using it this way, `this` will be your `widget` and you can make use of any `dojo` module that you require or any `function/property` of your widget.

The other way is using the module `dojo/on` as in your question, but, notice that the scope of the function will be change it, so you will need to adjust it either using `dojo/_base/lang` or the native [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) of javascript. Read this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023416/could-somebody-explain-to-me-what-exactly-is-happening-in-the-dojos-dojo-on/39023564#39023564) for more info about it.

Also I recommend to read [Understanding _WidgetBase](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/understanding_widgetbase/index.html)

Comment: As far as I understand your code and the links provided are very useful when creating a custom widget. I just want to handle the `onClick` event on standard widgets. Trying to add `onClick:myOnClick` to `data-dojo-props` and define the handler as above leads to `ReferenceError: myOnClick not defined`

Comment: Perhaps I haven't understand yet the `dojo` basics.